# How to tell gdb/eclipse not to stop on signal xyz

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging an c++ application under eclipse/gdb/ubuntu.
The Application raises periodically a signal SIGUSR1. (there is an installed sighandler).

On each signal, the debugger suspends the application and I've to press Resume.

How can I setup gdb under eclipse **not** to stop/ suspend a signal?

Comment: In gdb this is done with the `handle` command, like `handle SIGUSR1 nostop noprint`.  If Eclipse gives you a gdb console, just type that.  Otherwise, maybe you can put it into the appropriate `.gdbinit`.

Comment: `.gdbinit` location can be specified at Debug configuration properties, on Debugger tab.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the job:

```
handle all nostop pass
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Snip of gdb signal setup]
**strong text**

I am sharing snip of my eclipse setup which worked for me.
Hope it helps other.